# What does the statement "to qualify the use of a type in that namespace" mean in C#

Tags: c#, directive, using

I am a beginner in C# and came across the below error when using the `Console.WriteLine` function.

```
The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context
```

My understanding of the `using` keyword is that it acts like a `require` or `import` in JavaScript.

So I then added the statement `using System;` at the top on the namespace file since a suggestion from the IDE gave me something like `System.Console`. Now I do not have the error anymore.

Out of curiosity I went to the C# docs in the [using Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) section.
And there is the following state:

*The using directive has three uses:*

*To allow the use of types in a namespace so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace:*

What does the part -  *so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace:* mean.

And why the `using` keyword is called a directive or what is a directive in general programming in contrast to the directives I use for example in Angular?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it means so you can do Console instead of qualifying it as: System.Console, similar to how in Cpp you would use std::cout if you did not declare the std namespace

Comment: "to qualify the use of a type in that namespace" That means that in order to use the `Console`-class within the `System`-namespace you´d have to write `System.Console` everytime you´re using that type. Now imagine you have more namespaces, then writing `Namespace.Another.AThrid.MyType` again and again becomes quite anoying.

Comment: Would it be correct also to say, that a directive in this sense would be instructions for how the compiler should compile the other libraries you are using?

Comment: You can also write your own console. So you can write using MyConsole and when you will write in code Console.WriteLine() it will call your console instead of System Console. 

What if... if you have both, using System and using MyConsole and you will call Console.Write(), Visual Studio will throw error, because it doesnt know which console you want to use

Comment: Thanks guys your explanations gave me some light :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does the part - so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace: mean.

C# distinguishes between *simple names*, which have a name and an optional type argument, like `String` or `List<int>`, and *qualified names* which have multiple names separated by dots, like `System.String` or `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>`.

When you have a `using` directive, you can elide the used qualifier.

> And why the using keyword is called a directive or what is a directive in general programming

In C# we have *declarations* like `namespace Foo` or `class Bar` or `void M() {}`  We have *statements*, like `foreach(var foo in bar) blah();` What then is `using System;` ?  It's not a declaration; no new item is *declared*.  It's not a *statement* -- statements are control flow elements, but the using directive introduces no control flow.  It *directs* the compiler to have a particular rule for resolving names, and so it is a *directive*.

All of this information is in the C# specification. **I strongly recommend that you get yourself a copy of the spec and consult it when you have questions like these**. That will be faster and easier for you than posting a question here.

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation, so concise, sure I will use the docs from now on instead, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> What does the part - *so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace*: mean?

There's a static class `Math` within the `System` namespace. You could reference its static method `Min` like this without any `using`:

```
var z = System.Math.Min( x, y );
```

or you could get rid of `System.` by `using` the `System` namespace:

```
using System;
[...]
var z = Math.Min( x, y );
```

or you could get even rid of `Math.` (since C# 6):

```
using static System.Math;
[...]
var z = Min( x, y );
```

The third option basically allows you to treat static classes as namespaces.